# configure and make valgrind for ARMV7

Tags: linux, arm, valgrind

I'm trying to configure valgrind 3.8.1 to work on ARM V7.
I first run 
./configure  --host=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi

Then I run make. But after the make I get the following errors:

```
echo "# This is a generated file, composed of the following suppression rules:" >       default.supp
echo "# " exp-sgcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp glibc-2.X-drd.supp glibc-2.34567-  NPTL-helgrind.supp glibc-2.X.supp  >> default.supp
cat exp-sgcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp glibc-2.X-drd.supp glibc-2.34567-NPTL-  helgrind.supp glibc-2.X.supp  >> default.supp
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/include'
Making all in VEX
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I.. -I../include -I../VEX/pub -DVGA_arm=1 -DVGO_linux=1 -    DVGP_arm_linux=1 -DVGPV_arm_linux_vanilla=1 -Ipriv  -m32 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -O2 -g   -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-   declarations -Wno-format-zero-length -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -marm -mcpu=cortex-a8    -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-long-long  -Wno-pointer-   sign -fno-stack-protector -MT libvex_arm_linux_a-main_globals.o -MD -MP -MF   .deps/libvex_arm_linux_a-main_globals.Tpo -c -o libvex_arm_linux_a-main_globals.o `test -f    'priv/main_globals.c' || echo './'`priv/main_globals.c
`-mcpu=' is deprecated. Use `-mtune=' or '-march=' instead.
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-marm"
priv/main_globals.c:1: error: bad value (cortex-a8) for -mtune= switch
make[3]: *** [libvex_arm_linux_a-main_globals.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/amir/valgrind/valgrind-3.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error, have you managed to fix it yet?

Answer (score 0):

cross-compiling valgrind is not a straight forward there are many fixes to cross-compile it for ARMv7.

So there are patches available. apply this patches from here
 http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/valgrind